# VSTO FormRegionShowing and FormRegionClosing event not firing

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Good Evening,

I have an outlook addin that was working in 2007 but not in 2010.  I had to make some changes in the [regionName].Designer.cs file to implement the IFormRegionFactory.  I have made those changes and now my form region appears as expected on every AppointmentItem.

However, it does not appear that the FromRegionShowing event and FormRegionClosing events are being fired.  They are in the InitializeComponent private method of the partial class of my region which inherits from FormRegionBase as:

```
 this.FormRegionShowing += new System.EventHandler(this.[class]Region_FormRegionShowing);
 this.FormRegionClosed += new System.EventHandler(this.[class]Region_FormRegionClosed);
```

Not sure why the event are not wired up.  Do I need to wire it up in the TimeTrackingRegionFactory partial class the implements the IFormRegionFactory like the FormRegionInitializing event.

Any help and I'll put in a good word to Santa for you.  :)

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 0):

Rather embarrassing but apparently I declared the following in my partial class [class]Region that hid the inherited member FormRegionBase.OUtlookFormRegion:

```
public IFormRegionFactory Factory { get; set; }
public FormRegion OutlookFormRegion { get; set; }
public object OutlookItem { get; private set; }
public FormRegionManifest Manifest { get; private set; }
public event EventHandler FormRegionShowing;
public event EventHandler FormRegionClosed;
```

Deleting these worked.